# How do i fill a listview of image without OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm using android.support.v4.app.Fragments and i have to fill out a list of picture that i get get them as array of bytes,

this is my code

```
final NewSite site = data.get(position);

        if(null != site.getImage()){
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(site.getImage(), 0, site.getImage().length, options);
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
        if(null != site.getDescription())
            holder.informations.setText(site.getDescription() + "    " + position);
        if(site.getListOfChildren() != null && site.getListOfChildren().size() != 0){
            Log.i("BitmapFactory", site.getListOfChildren().size() + "");
            for (NewSite newSite : site.getListOfChildren()) {


                if(null != newSite.getImage()){
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(newSite.getImage(),0,newSite.getImage().length, options);
                    view = new ImageView(context);

                    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(30, 20));
                    view.setPadding(2, 0, 2, 2);

                    view.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    holder.listOfImages.addView(view);
                    bmp = null;
                    //view = null;
                }
```

and always i get `OutOfMemoryError Exception`

Comment: use lay list of universal image loader

Comment: compress all the images..

Comment: I use this lib often: https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Answer (score 1):

I would display a [subsampled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) version of the image (if you're not doing it already, your options code isn't in your question), this will take up a lot less memory because it reduces the quality of the `Bitmap`. You can always display a higher res version of the `Bitmap` when clicked.

I use this code in one of my apps to subsample the image so that I don't run out of memory.

```
BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o2.inSampleSize = yourSampleSize;

Bitmap returnBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), o2);
```

Hope this helps you find a solution. Out of memory issues with `Bitmap` handling is never fun.